# How to store drawable in an array

Tags: android, drawable

I want to download a bunch of images and would like to store it as drawable in an array. So I tried declaring a drawable array.But it returns me `nullPointer` exception when I access that array.

My question is, how to declare an array type as drawable ?

Comment: Show us your initial declaration and initialization. My bet is it's not initialized right.

Comment: how are you storing the images in the array - share the code

Comment: Drawable[] image;  for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();draw[i]=Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");

Comment: you can use ArrayList<Drawable> or ArrayList<Bitmap>.

Comment: you haven't actually created your array. You have just declared it. you need Drawable[] image = new Drawable[some value];

Comment: @fleetway76 How silly of me. I totally forgot to initialize my array.  That was the only mistake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

an array of drawables would be declared like:

```
int numDrawables = 10;
Drawable[] drawableArray = new Drawable[numDrawables];
```

to fill the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numDrawables; i++){
    // get a drawable from somewhere
    Drawable drawable = new Drawable();
    drawableArray[i] = drawable;
}
```

to access the array:

```
Drawable aDrawable = drawableArray[0];
```

This is basic java, If you are getting null pointer exceptions, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: How silly of me. I totally forgot to initialize my array.  That was the only mistake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an hashMap , and put the keys as urls for example , and to value is the drawable that you download :

```
HashMap<String,Drawable> myDrawables = new HashMap<String,Drawable>();
//before you download the images, you can test if your drawable is already downloaded, 
// with looking for his url in the Hashmap , 
.....
myDrawables.put(urlOfYourDrawable, yourDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store list of elements(any type) dynamically use the classes in the collection. why because Array size is static.
Example:

```
ArrayList<Generic> list=new ArrayList<Generic>();

list.add(Generic);
```