# Click button and that button waits for second button on activity to be pushed. Game board. How to accomplish?

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

I wasn't exactly sure how to briefly paraphrase my question in the title, so please forgive me as I never post questions until now. I am new to Android/Java for starters, as the main language I have used so far is C++. My question is that I have a game board layout (similar to checkers/chess). When it is the user’s turn, they are to click the piece they want to move on the board and then the blank location they would like to move it to. How can this be accomplished? Up until this point I have implemented onClickListeners that never rely on another button in the activity to be clicked afterwards and wait for the user to do so.

**Brief information on my project currently (unsure if needed):**

I am currently using an ImageButtons array (of size 36) and a two dimensional integer array to hold the information of each of the buttons, as they are displayed in a GridLayout in a 6 X 6 fashion. In my MainActivity class I have implemented the OnClickListener and created a switch statement in onClick() for each of the button ids.

I am not sure how much more information is needed on my code for help or if it is completly irrelevant. I tried looking on the internet before choosing to ask finding nothing. It is always possible though I was not correctly phrasing my issue. Thank you to everyone in advance!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code it is hard to say what you are doing wrong/right. But if you have the images stored in an `Array` then when they click on one `image` that can be put into a variable which is used to place on the `View` that they click on next. If you have a more precise question then please post relevant code and error messages from what you have tried, if any. Hope this helps

Comment: I know it is difficult to help with an answer without seeing my code. The only reason I did not include it in the post is because it is part of a project for my AI class. I have not tried anything yet at this point because I was honestly not sure what to even try. The idea of storing the image sounds quite plausible though. I have been changing the picture using button.setImageResource(R.drawable.picturename) so I am not exactly sure how to store it. I shall look into it and get back to this post(so long as I remember!) if I figure it out. Thank you for your input, I appreciate it!!! :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. [Here is a SO question on how to store drawables in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213444/how-to-store-drawable-in-an-array) hope it helps. If this answer helps you then you may accept it. Or if you have any further questions, feel free to ask. Good luck to you

Answer (score 0):

after a user click's a piece store that info in a member variable like a current piece and then on second click check if the previous is not null, the current clicked space is empty and start your animation by posting to a runnable implementation. this is the simple logic part. where are you having problem exactly

Answer (score 0):

To optimize your code to change images what you can do is custom animations on the imageview. You can change the position of the image with animation without having to create or store an image. (If you use images bitmap a lot you have a very good chance of running into OutOfMemory exceptions and this will happen on top end phones very easily

Comment: Thank you. I will keep this in mind since I have algorithms yet to be implemented for the computer player that will eat enough memory on their own! I'm not used to having to think about memory from doing small programs in C++ so it is always good to have a reminder! :)

Answer (score 0):

### How to Move a Button and Change the Button Image

I would put a single `Button` on every `GridView` position.
Then, I would use `button.setBackground()` and `button.setVisibility()` to display and hide the buttons with various images. In this way, the buttons will appear to move, but you are really just displaying a different button.

I recommend this because it is easier to change the visibility and image properties of a button than it is to actually move the button, although both methods are possible.

You will maintain a 1 dimensional array of images[n] and a 2 dimensional array of buttons[6,6].

As an example, suppose you want to move image[5] from grid position (1,2) to position (3,4):

```
// Hide the button at (1,2);
button[1,2].setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);

// Display the button at (3,4) with image #5.
button[3,4].setBackground(image[5]);
button[3,4].setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
```

Additionally, if your button images are stored in your resources, you could efficiently use `button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image-5-id);`

---

The instructions above discuss how to move a Button, but now how to trigger one Button to be moved and then trigger the location into which to move the Button.

To accomplish this, you will have to define two states, such as:

```
private final static int STATE_PICK_BUTTON = 0;
private final static int STATE_PICK_LOCATION = 1;
private int state;
```

Initialize `state = STATE_PICK_BUTTON;`

- When the system is in the first state `STATE_PICK_BUTTON`, all button
  presses identified in your `onClick()` function memorize a grid
  position to move from, and in some cases transition the system into
  the second state: `STATE_PICK_LOCATION`.
- When the system is in the second state `STATE_PICK_LOCATION`, all
  button presses actually move the button from the memorized grid
  position to the grid position of this button press.
- Of course, you will have to do all sorts of error checking to make
  sure you are allowed to move a button before triggering the state
  transition.

---

Finally, the above suggestion may not work, because it may be impossible to click an invisible button. If this is the case, instead of changing the visibility of Buttons in empty grid locations, leave all the buttons `Button.VISIBLE` and use a fully transparent Button image for the buttons representing empty grid spaces.